# Are there statistics that show the percentage of times you should fold at each stage of Texas Hold'em?

Tags: strategy, statistics

More specifically, the percentage of times over many hands that the most successful players fold pre-flop,and after the flop, turn and river. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is likely to be very situation dependent.

There is however, a section in the PokerTracker tool that analyses the range of common actions that players have taken, (eg. Cbet flop, fold to flop Cbet, 3bet stats, aggression stats, etc.), and gives a broad estimate of how often profitable players are taking those actions, whilst comparing your stats against those ranges. It should lead people to dig deeper into those hand histories to find out why.

Those empirically formed data sets will provide guidance, but intuitively there can't be a recognised best set of frequencies to take with *any* action that I know of, unless you and your opponents are both playing Game Theory Optimal strategies.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify the tracker program are using, i assume you own *Pokertracker*, although *HEM* has a similar functionality, but you have to paid for it.

Poker tracker specifically has a free tool embedded called *Leaktracker* which is only for `cash` (under `View Stats -> LeakTracker`). This tool handles exactly what you want, it shows you a statistic range that successful players have in say `VPIP, PFR` and more stats, distributed across all table positions of either *full-ring / short tables*. Your job is to play a lot of hands and see *how you fare* against those successful players and tweak your game if you find your stats differ a lot from those of successful players.

You asked about *how much you should fold per street*. I think the word `should` is wrong to be used that way as situations are specific per Villain. However, what you can do is trying to emulate the stats of successful players as mentioned above, in per-street basis like the `Fold to Turn C-Bet` as example, while reading/interpreting the connection between specific Villain play and his stats. For example, i'm going to fold a ton against a `Nit` if he double-barrels me on `Turn` rather against an `aggro` player that happens to have a gravy `Turn C-Bet` of `70+`, just an example.